# MYSQL Column contains the same value

Tags: mysql, lines

In mysql I have a column (LANG) that contains the same value (EN), the number of lines exceeds the 100,000 lines at the moment

The column can take the same value among these
IT, FR, DE, ES, EN
is there any solution to optimizes the table?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean "optimize the table"?

Comment: Is this a de-duplication problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column that contain one of a known values (from a list) you should use an `ENUM` column type (and not a `string/varchar` one, for example):

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `LANG` ENUM('EN','IT','FR','DE','ES','EN') NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The [`ENUM` storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#idm140400901996160) are

> 1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of enumeration values (65,535 values maximum)

Comment: Sorry
I was not clear about my question and I do not know if it is doable.
Imagine a column with thousands of line with same value is it possible to do something? To keep a single line for example

Comment: I really don't understand what you need and what is the problem. Please try to clarify.